# React-joyride packing working locally but not after deployment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, build, package

I added react-joyride in my nextjs app I styled and added steps it's working perfectly
on localhost but after yarn build and deployment its not showing there
and I served the build locally but it's not even included in the build.